# Syntax Error при использовании buildozer kivy

Tags: python, android, ubuntu, kivy, buildozer

Занимаюсь созданием приложения на python kivy для андроида. Для компиляции apk использую виртуальную машину с ОС Ubuntu-64bit. Версия питона 3.8. Проект склонирован с git-репозитория. Buildozer устанавливала с помощью команды: `git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer.git`.
Проблема: при запуске команды в директории проекта: `buildozer init` следующий результат:

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==1.5.1.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 480, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2693, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2324, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2330, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.5.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import buildozer.buildops as buildops
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.5.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/buildops.py", line 15, in <module>
    import pexpect
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .pty_spawn import spawn, spawnu
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .spawnbase import SpawnBase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 224
    def expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False):
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

заранее спасибо за ответы.